# rails inline_svg with carrierwave uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inline-svg

i have a problem with using inline_svg gem with carrierwave uploaded svg. When im inspecting rendered html in place where svg should be i've got error that file cannot be found. Is this because file is not placed in asset pipeline?

Comment: How are you using the `inline_svg` helper? Show some code. It does not need to point to a file on the assets pipeline but you have to provide an IO object reading the file in that case. https://github.com/jamesmartin/inline_svg#usage

Comment: Thanks to Your's info about IO object it is now working :) Thank You very much